# List Of String not inserting data

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, list

Running into an issue where i am trying to `Insert()` data into a list `Of String` but for some reason it is not inserting the data.

```
Private Sub Build(param 1, param 2, param 3,)
  Dim dataList As New List(Of String)
  Dim charcode as String = ""
  Dim index As Integer = 0


  For i As Integer = 0 To rowCount - 1
    dataList.Add("data" & i)
  Next

  'dataNum is of int value (zero based) from 0 - whatever number
  For Each Item As String In root.Subfields
    charcode = GetChar(Item, 2)
    If Not charCodes.Contains(charcode) Then
      dataList(dataNum).Insert(index, Item)
      index += 1
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Using Visual Studio debugger i can see that the `dataList` is being populated
[image]

But when we get down to the `For Each` the data is not being populated into the list under the appropriate collection (data1, data2)

[image]

What's going on here? Surely this should work (right?).

thank you.

EDIT:

Here is an image of what i am trying to accomplish:

[image]

as you can see i have a main collection with collections or sub fields inside that one.

Comment: Strings are immutable. If you call Insert on a string you need to catch the return value of the insert where the change is returned. The original string is not changed. By the way, do you realize that you are Inserting into a string and not into the list?

Comment: You should also turn on Option Strict - where is `index` declared?  It comes out of nowhere

Comment: @Plutonix `index` is declared in the same spot as `dataList` & `charcode`. Apologies as i missed it and did not place it in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds from the question text like you're trying to insert a whole new string as a new entry in your list. Look carefully at this line:

```
dataList(dataNum).Insert(index, Item)
```

When this code executes, it first retrieves the `List(Of String)` object referred to by the `dataList` variable, and then looks up the *specific string object* at index `dataNum`. Now you have a single string (*not* a List anymore) and you call the *string's* `Insert()` method. It's not the `Insert()` method for the list.

To fix this, I'd need to know more about how you're using the `index` variable that's not referred to or declared anywhere else in the code or the question text. It's not clear how you expect this to be used.

Or maybe you really wanted just a string. If so, that's *not* what your question text is asking for. But if you're really trying to insert additional text into that specific string, you still have a problem. String objects in .Net *don't change* (we say they are "immutable"). When you use a method like `Insert()`, rather than changing that string instance, it produces and returns a *new string object*. With that in mind, you need to assign that new string somewhere. That would look like this:

```
dataList(dataNum) = dataList(dataNum).Insert(index, Item)
```

But, again, that's not what the text of your question is asking for. I'm including it here because it better matches the code sample.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have updated my code to include the variable `index` declaration. What i am trying to do is get the `Item` data to be in a sub-collection, if you will, under the `data[0,1]` collections. your second suggestion was very close to what i need. Apologies if my question text was uninformative or off. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `List(Of List(Of String))` (That is a thing, btw. I've used it before).

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. If you call Insert on a string you need to catch the return value of the insert where the change is returned. The original string is not changed. By the way, do you realize that you are Inserting into a string and not into the list?

If you want to insert a string inside the current list you need something like this (It is not very clear from the code above if you need to use the variable *datanum* or the variable *index* to choose the appropriate position in the list)

```
For Each Item As String In root.Subfields
  charcode = GetChar(Item, 2)
  If Not charCodes.Contains(charcode) Then
    dataList.Insert(index, Item)
    index += 1
  End If
Next
```

From your comment below it seems that you want only replace an element of the list with a new value. In this case you can treat the list like it was an array and write something like

```
dataList(0) = newItem;
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the reply. I am aware i can `insert` into `dataList` as you have mentioned but I am seeking a way to place the `Item` inside either the 1st (0) or second (1) collection. Both of the images show the collection.

Comment: If you want to replace the item at position 0 in the list then it is something like _dataList(0) = newItem;_ There is no Insert involved